# mount -o rw,<user> /dev/src1 /media/<mount-name> not working

Tags: mount, permissions, usb-drive

I have burned the ubuntu iso distribution on my flash drive and I boot into ubuntu from the flash USB drive. Note that I am using the option 'Try without installing ubuntu' while booting.

The problem is if I try to use any other usb device all the file system on that usb device appears read only to the default `ubuntu` user as well as for the `root`. The volume appears as read-only.

Next, I tried to remount the usb device and make it rw using

`sudo mount -o rw,ubuntu /dev/src1 /media/<mount-device-name>`

While the command seems to succeed and I get no errors, the device doesnt become read-write. The mount entries in fstab still show the device as read-only.

Any suggestions as what is going wrong?

Comment: there are seem to be typos in your command - what is the "ubuntu" option? Also, /dev/src1 should be /dev/sdc1. Also, usually the mount point is a subdierctory under /media, not the /media directory itself

Comment: ubuntu was the default user when I got booted on to ubuntu

Answer (score 4):

`ubuntu` is not a valid mount option. First you need to know the user ID of the user you want to allow read/write access. In the case of a Live session user, it is `999`. The command becomes:

```
sudo mount -o rw,uid=999 /dev/src1 /mnt
```

You should not mount a partition on `/media` because `/media` is reserved for holding multiple mounted devices. Also, consider using the File browser for mounting the partition.

I was assuming that you are using a filesystem that does not support UNIX file permissions, such as FAT32 and NTFS. If you are using a file permissions-aware filesystem, you have to make yourself the owner of the files. Note: dangerous command ahead, so check that you *are* actually changing the ownership of your USB partition and not your root filesystem:

```
sudo chown -R ubuntu: /media/your-usb-drive
```

*(note the colon, this causes the group membership to be updated to `ubuntu` too)*

Comment: In the future you can find the `uid` of a user using: `id <user>` Where `<user>` is the name of the user you wish to find the ID for.

Comment: Worth to note that `uid` option is not a general one, but it is valid only for some filesystem types, as for example vfat.